# How can I reposition the map center to fit the infobubble?

Tags: here-api

I can easily get the marker to be centered. However, it does not count in the size of the infobubble.

I'd like to reposition the map when clicking a marker such that the info bubble fits. This can be as simple as aligning center horizontally and bottom vertically.

[image]

I tried manipulating the position for centering the marker. However, that surprisingly moves the marker to the new location also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add below JS snippet, as it allows marker movement ,but restrict its movement when the map is dragged.

I hope this will help you to achieve the desired outcome.

```
<script>
function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior){

  var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:42.35805, lng:-71.0636});

// Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
  marker.draggable = true;
  map.addObject(marker);

  // disable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when starting to drag a marker object:
  map.addEventListener('dragstart', function(ev) {

    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
      behavior.disable();
    }},false);


  // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map
  // when dragging has completed

  map.addEventListener('dragend', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target;
    if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
      behavior.enable();
    }
  }, false);

  // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker
  // as necessary


map.addEventListener('drag', function(ev) {
    var target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
    if (target instanceof mapsjs.map.Marker) {
      target.setPosition(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX, pointer.viewportY));
    }
  }, false);
}
  </script>
```